# .NET - how to fix startup?

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, asp.net, windows-vista, service

I have IIS and several versions of Microsoft .NET installed on my Windows Vista computer.

When I tried to start a particular .NET Framework version, this error message appeared:

[image]

How can I fix this error and get them both to show "Started" in the status bar of services.msc (the services tab)?

This is for use with my modaspdotnet project I'm developing on my Apache server.

I'm not sure what I'm doing here; and I've had a brief Google around, but couldn't find very much.

Answer (score 3):

This service does not have anything to do with running .NET applications.  It's a service to precompile newly-globally-installed assemblies so they don't need to be Just-in-Time compiled.